# Using a c# program to send a parameter to an excel file, so that it uses the parameter to send it to a stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, sql, excel

I have a question, I have a c# program that saves a companyID on a session.

The user can click and download an excel file, and that file, when opened, calls an sql stored procedure that populares the sheets.

The thing is, I need for the excel file to HAVE that companyID that is in the session, so that it filters all this information by company (that is,receives the company ID from the c# code,sends the companyID as a parameter for the procedure, and then populates the tables)

Could anyone help me?

Also, i have another problem. When the user asks to download the excel file, the user shoudl be able to also download it as a pdf.

Is there any way that i can , i dont know, maybe open an instance of excel in the background, so taht it calls the stored procedure, and then convert everything to PDF?

thank you !

Comment: why don't you run the SQL store procedure SERVER SIDE and with its results create the output file?

Comment: Thank you! the thing is i need to create all kinds of graphs with it too, and i was thinking that running the procedure server side, and not in the excel file may mess up or not allow me to format the graphs the way i am supposed to , i was looking into the option of using 'report viewer' or 'reporting services', does that seem like a better solution? because with that i just generate a report and the viewer itself has options to export to excel or pdf...is there a solution that may be better? its just theres so many reports,calling server side may be a pain, but any other alteration will be 2

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just simply call the stored procedure in your website, and then force a Download Dialog with the data on the page?

Also, [Check this out](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Excel_PDF_Word_ExportWiz.aspx), it's a Winform app that makes exactly what you need. So maybe you can look into the Code and perhaps get something useful out of it.

Good luck!

Comment: Oh i see, it seems to be a helpful app, i was thinking of using report viewer or reporting service, what do you think? im sorry but i dont understand what you mean by forcing a download dialog =(

Answer (score 0):

You can probably hack together a Excel Automation / VBA solution that modifies VBA code that runs the proc when it opens. There are tons of downsides to this since VBA code embedded in excel spreadsheet has to be trusted by the user to run.

Instead you're much better of using a reporting tool to render the formats that you want. Since in the comments you mention SSRS you can use [ServerReport.Render Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252159%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) to do this.

Pretty much every reporting solution has a similar way to do this via an API.